# Set Directory Permissions CHMOD with JSCH

Tags: java, jsch

In Unix, how do I set the directory permissions with JSCH?  I am looking to do drwxrwxrwx.  Filezilla says the integer for that is 775 but JSCH is not setting the permissions correctly.  After JSCH sets the permissions Filezilla says that it is 407.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file permissions code in Unix (`777`, for example) are octal, not decimal. As in: when you do something like `chmod -R 777`, the digits are interpreted as octal input instead of decimal input.

This system comes from the fact that there are 3 permission groups:

- owner
- group
- world

and each group has an "on/off bit" for:

- read
- write
- execute

so octal-base is sufficient to represent all possible permission configurations for a group. The 3 octal-digits each correspond to a permission group.

(For further reading on this: http://www.december.com/unix/ref/chmod.html)

Back to your problem with JSCH: the decimal integer `775`'s octal representation is `0o1407`, my suspicion is that the decimal 775 is actually sent instead of the octal 775, and FileZilla may very well be truncating the stuff to the left of the 3rd least significant digit of `0o1407` (because it's not unreasonable for it to assume there's nothing past the 3rd least significant bit)

Now, `509` is the decimal representation of octal `775`, try using that with JSCH instead.

Answer (score 9):

This works to me:

```
sftp.chmod(Integer.parseInt(permissionStringInDecimal,8), str_Directory+fileName);
```

Comment: To be clear, permissions like "755" and "644" are _octal_ numbers, not decimal. Storing them in a variable named `permissionStringInDecimal` could be confusing.

Comment: This just an example of Jsch's awful apis.

Answer (score 0):

here is a short and a full example of how to can easyly use Jsch to change a chmod by
using the usual way to decrib a CHMOD permission

=========================================================
short answer :
    int chmodInt = Integer.parseInt(chmod, 8);
    channel.chmod(chmodInt, fileLinux);

=========================================================
Full Example :

```
package example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import main.services.ServiceSSH;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

public class ExampleChmod {

    @Test
    public void testchmod() throws JSchException, SftpException, IOException {
        Session session = ServiceSSH.getSession(); // Use your own session Factory
        Date dateStart = new Date();
        chmod("/home/user/launcher.sh", "777", session);
        Date dateEnd = new Date();
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println(dateEnd.getTime() - dateStart.getTime() + "ms");
    }

    public static void chmod(String fileLinux, String chmod, Session session) throws JSchException, SftpException {
        ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        chmod(fileLinux, chmod, channel);
        channel.disconnect();

    }

    private static void chmod(String fileLinux, String chmod, ChannelSftp channel) throws SftpException {
        int chmodInt = Integer.parseInt(chmod, 8);
        channel.chmod(chmodInt, fileLinux);
    }
}
```

Comment: this answer is trying to help, please dont down vote, if there is a mistake just mention the mistakes

Answer (score 0):

it's all about server configurations.[image]

just untick Automatically rename existing files on overwrite